Fisher's information for a function that consist in many indicator functions
I have the following pdf:
$$
f(x) = \theta I_{(-\frac{1}{2},0]}+ I_{(0,\frac{1}{2}]}+(1-\theta) I_{(\frac{1}{2},1]}
$$

I've tried the following

\begin{align}
    I(\theta) &=-E[\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2} \log f_{x} (x,\theta)] \\
              &=-E[\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2} \log (\theta I_{(-\frac{1}{2},0]}+ I_{(0,\frac{1}{2}]}+(1-\theta) I_{(\frac{1} 
                    {2},1]})] \\
              &=E[\frac{d}{d\theta} \frac {I_{(-\frac{1}{2},0]}(x)-I_{(\frac{1}{2},1)}(x)}{I_{(- 
                \frac{1}{2},0]}+ I_{(0,\frac{1}{2}]}+(1-\theta) I_{(\frac{1}{2},1]}}] \\
              &=E[\frac{(I_{(-\frac{1}{2},0]}(x)-I_{(\frac{1}{2},1)}(x))^2}{(I_{(-\frac{1}{2},0]}+ I_{(0,\frac{1}{2}]}+(1-\theta) I_{(\frac{1}{2},1]})^2}]
\end{align}
´

At this point i do not have idea what to do. i' trying to arrive at asymptotic distribution of the MLE when it is properly normalized. Then im using the following property

$$
\theta _{MLE} \sim N(0,I(\theta)^{-1})
$$

Then I need to arrive at an expression to compare this approximation to the MLE that I calculated previously and finally obtain $I(\theta)$ but i can't arrive to that.


write $f_X(x) = \theta^{ I_{(-1/2,0)} } 1^{ I_{(0,1/2]}} (1-\theta)^{ I_{(1/2,1]} }$

Integrate piece by piece for the 3 regions individually.
